# Inverse Error function of $x$ if $x>1$

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics

Okay, you can probably guess what my question is based on the title, but I think I already know the answer and I just need some verification.

As a math enthusiast, I've noticed a trend in multivariate functions (functions where domain values are allowed to repeat).  For every true function, each x value has at least one y value and vice versa.  This only occurs in true functions, however, as opposed to functions created solely for human convenience, like the absolute value function, the ceiling function, or the square wave.

That being said, I've analyzed the error function on a wide variety of numbers (real and imaginary), but I never seemed to generate a real number with a real part greater than one.

After a lot of analyzing, I came to the conclusion that the error function behaves much like the arctangent function, in the sense that as a multivariate function, each x would have multiple y values each equidistant from each other.  The logic behind this is, due to the Reimmann sphere model, after infinity, numbers start all over again from negative infinity.  Since the error function is the integral of the bell curve from 0 to x, and the bell curve has a finite area evaluated on the real axis, the error function could also be represented as the integral from 0 to infinity to negative infinity back to x. Again, due to the Reimann sphere model, this would make sense.  So, by this conclusion,

$$erf^{(-1)}(x)=erf^{(-1)}(x-2)=erf^{(-1)}(x-4)=...$$

But, I still need some verification from other people before I can confirm this.  If you could follow along, what do you think?[image]

Comment: No, this is wrong.  $\text{erf}(x)$ for real $x$ is always in the interval $(-1,1)$.  It is not a multivalued function.  It is a single-valued entire function.

Comment: As for generating real values $> 1$, you have for example $\text{erf}(z) = 2$ where $z \approx -2.752568927 \pm 3.270707303 i$.

Comment: And in what sense is $|x$ "not a true function? It looks as if you have tried to string together some powerful-sounding words but your statements don't quite make sense.

Comment: Well yes, but only by standard definition, in the same way that arcsin(x) is only supposed to have a range from $$(-\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2)$$, but technically by the laws of the universe is multivalued.  So, I guess I'm not so much referring to erf(x) as I am the true mathematical variation of it.  Idk.  Do you know what $$erf^{(-1)}(12)$$ is?

Comment: |x| is not a true function because it's derivative isnt defined.

Comment: The closest points to $0$ in $\text{erf}^{-1}(12)$ are approximately $.4941809038 \pm 1.952070741 i$.

Comment: |x| is not a true function because it's derivative isnt defined.  $$(|x+\Delta|-|x-\Delta|)/ \Delta $$   is not equal to $$ (|x+\Delta i|-|x-\Delta i|) / \Delta $$

Comment: @MathMachine I suggest you learn some complex analysis.

Comment: erf(.4941809038+1.952070741i) is close to twelve but still has an imaginary part.

Comment: Look I'm not trying to start an argument with you.

Comment: What the heck is a "true function"?  Certainly there are functions that are not bijections...and functions that are not differentiable.  Unfortunately, when you start to develop your own vocabulary for things, we can't really help you because you haven't provided a definition.

Comment: Never mind.  I think weve reached an impass, let's just logically agree that at least one of us isn't thinking about this the right way.  I appreciate your input, though, and maybe I am wrong.  Who knows?

Comment: The term "multivalued function" has a meaning different from the one you seem to be intending.

Comment: You know what, I truly appreciate each and every one of you for calling me a moron in the meanest, most condescending way possible.  I've already started a research paper on this topic and I should be ready to submit it in a matter of 5 years.  All I asked was for someone to look into my theory WITHOUT using Wikipedia, rather using logic, reasoning and analyzing, but I guess that was too much to ask.  I'm not coming back here.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry i made my explanation vague.  I honestly thought everyone else was familiar with how the absolute value and rounding functions weren't the same types of functions as say y=x².  But, looking back through my college notes, I had realized that this concept was never taught or even brought up, so I guess your confusion is justified.  The following are examples of artificial functions: absolute value, the real part function, the imaginary part function, the argument function, the sgn(x) function, and the complex conjugate.  I'll explain why in the next comment.

Comment: Neither of the functions I listed can be derived without another function in the list.  |z|=√(zconj(z))=√(Re²(z)+Im²(z))=z/sgn(z)= e^(Re(ln(x))).  And no, $ ^{∞} \sqrt{z ^{∞}} $ does not count, as there are theoretically infinitely many answers, each with a different argument. (You can try to use that bias to find a formula for the argument function, but I've tried it, trust me, it doesn't work).

Comment: You may think that that fact is insignificant, but if you think about it, almost any function can be derived by some combination of arithmetic functions, inverses, exponents, and derivation/integration (which if you think of it, is technically an arithmetic function, as an integral is an infinite sum and a derivative is a subtraction problem with infinitesimally small numbers).

Comment: You may think this an arbitrary system, but the rules make sense for several reasons: the inverse rule makes sense because if a graph is natural, then flipping it about the line y=x would be natural as well, since it has the same essential shape.  The exponential rule makes sense as $ a^x $ is just $ e^{xln(a)} $, and $e^x$ is just the inverse of ln(x), which is equal to $ \int_1^x \frac{1}x $

Comment: The integral rule makes sense if you just think of an integral as the product of x and an infinite sum.  With all of these rules, we can reduce every true function to a series of addition, subtraction, multipliction, and division problems.

Comment: Now, before someone points out that the basis of complex numbers involves absolute value and arguments, I will say that, while the concept of multiplying absolute values and addition of angles can be mathematically proven, in the proof, you can assume that z=x+yi, but the formula would still work if x or y was complex.  Let's assume z=3+4i.  However, instead of using x=3 and y=4, lets say x=2+i and y=3-i.  z=(2+i)+(3-i)i (yes, that equals 3+4i).

Comment: Under this premise, Re(z)=2+i and Im(z)=3-i.  |z|=√(Re²(z)+Im²(z))=√(11-2i), and $arg(z)=tan^{(-1)}((3-i)/(2+i))$.  Conj(z)=(2+i)-(3-i)i=1-2i.  Now, let's find the same values for z² (which equals -7+24i).  Re(z²)=Re²(z)-Im²(z)=(2+i)²-(3-i)²=-5+10i, and Im(z²)=2Re(z)Im(z)=2(2+i)(3-i)=14+2i.  Re(z²)+Im(z²)=(-5+10i)+(14+2i)i=-7+24i=z².  Let's keep going, |z²|=$\sqrt{Re²(z²)+Im²(z²)}$, which equals $\sqrt{(-5+10)²+(14+2i)²}$ which, according to my calculations, is 11-2i, which is the square of z's absolute value according to the top of the comment.

Comment: Finally, the argument, arg(z²)=$tan^{(-1)}(\frac{Im(z²)}Re(z²)) $  Im(z²)=14+2i, Re(z²)=-5+10i, $\frac{14+2i}{-5+10i} = \frac{-2-6i}5 $ according to the rules of complex numbers, arg(z²) should be twice arg(z), which as mentioned before is $tan^{(-1)}(\frac{3-i}{2+i})$, which is the same as $tan^{(-1)}(1-i)$   If you remember your rules of trigonometry, tan(2ø)=$\frac{2tan(ø)}{1-tan²(ø)}$.  If tan(ø)=1-i, tan(2ø)=$\frac{2-2i}{1-(1-i)²}$

Comment: $\frac{2-2i}{1-(1-i)²}=\frac{2-2i}{1+2i}=\frac{-2-6i}5$. Sound familiar?  As you can see, the rules of absolute value, complex parts, and arguments aren't unique.  That being said, these functions ARE USEFUL to humans, not to mention interesting.  Yes, I know, by definition, the real and imaginary parts must be represented as real, but when you toss aside all of the complex parts functions, all numbers behave the same (relatively speaking).  But, these functions are useful nonetheless to humans and our limited reality.

Comment: Okay, I guess the name of this type of function is “analytic”

Answer (score 1):

Your "analysis" of the error function is utterly wrong. The ${\rm erf}z$ is an entire function with an essential singularity at $z=\infty,$ so by Picard's theorem, it takes every complex value, except at most one. I don't know if there is such an exceptional value in this case, but neither do you. The error function is *not* periodic, though along certain directions, it can be described by Fresnel integrals, so it is oscillatory.
Study mathematics *before* making such claims.